# fetch fails to load resource when receiving 404

Tags: javascript, fetch

I got a method that fetches data from an API, but it logs errors when receiving an error response (404, 500).

I would just like to return 'undefined' as data if the status is an error, what's my mistake here, how do I get rid of the errors on my console?

**fetch.js**

```
export default (url, method, authorization, body) => {
    const headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
    if (authorization) headers.Authorization = localStorage.getItem('id_token');
    return fetch(url, {
        method,
        headers,
        body: JSON.stringify(body)
    }).then(res => res.ok ? res.json() : undefined)
    .catch(console.log);
}
```

**console**

[image: console errors]

**sources**

[image: sources]

Comment: Are you sure your code doesn't already work? Catching the error using a function like `console.log` should log out the error and return null. And failed network requests are logged out regardless if they're caught or not.

Comment: The fetch method doesn't reject when receiving an error, but response.ok will be false. The code returns undefined, but I want to get rid of the errors (which are not logged out because of the console.log

Comment: Oh, you can't hide those in the code. You can only hide them in the Chrome dev tools (using filtering etc).

Comment: Well, that's annoying. Thanks anyway for helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Chrome always shows an error in the console when any request returns a HTTP error code in the 4XX or 5XX range, there's not much you can do about that.

The reason your `catch` isn't triggering is because when you return something in a `then` (or a `catch`) then that puts the promise chain back into a success mode. If you want to put it into a failure mode, and trigger the next `catch`, then you need to return specifically a rejected Promise:

Try this instead:

```
export default (url, method, authorization, body) => {
  const headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
  if (authorization) headers.Authorization = localStorage.getItem('id_token')
  return fetch(url, {
    method,
    headers,
    body: JSON.stringify(body),
  })
    .then(res => {
      res.ok ? res.json() : Promise.reject(undefined)
    })
    .catch(console.log)
}
```

Comment: Yes, the catch is not supposed to be triggered. It is a fail-safe for when something unexpected happens. The error in the console just really bugged me.

Answer (score 1):

Every time that you add the .catch() , the code go there if there is an error and skip the (res) => part.

So if you want to get rid of the errors of your console you can:

```
export default (url, method, authorization, body) => {
    const headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
    if (authorization) headers.Authorization = localStorage.getItem('id_token');
    return fetch(url, {
        method,
        headers,
        body: JSON.stringify(body)
    }).then(res => res.ok ? res.json(console.log(res)) : undefined) // check the result directly
}
```

Comment: The fetch method doesn't reject when receiving an error, but response.ok will be false. The code returns undefined, but I want to get rid of the errors (which are not logged out because of the console.log